# How to define an infinite 2D array recursively in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell, and I like its graceful grammar. But I haven't found a suitable way to define an infinite 2D array -- for example, the Pascal Triangle:

```
1  1  1  1  1  ...
1  2  3  4  5  ...
1  3  6 10 15  ...
1  4 10 20 35  ...
1  5 15 35 70  ...
...
```

I know how to define a simple function:

```
pascal :: Int -> Int -> Int
pascal 1 _ = 1
pascal _ 1 = 1
pascal x y = (pascal (x - 1) y) + (pascal x (y - 1))
```

Since Haskell do not memorize function values, a call to `pascal 20 20` will *take a long time*. How could I define a fast version (like an infinite 2D array)?

Comment: In both cases, you should consider changing `Int` to `Integer` to avoid eventual integer overflow.

Comment: Obviously, an infinite 2D array cannot actually be created. In an imperative language you could have a data structure (such as `java.util.ArrayList` in Java) which is backed by an array which grows on demand, but in Haskell this would be problematic because resizing the array would be a side-effect. You would be able to observe the size of the array changing.

Comment: If you want your calls to `pascal` memoized you could just use, for example, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create the pascal triangle as an infinite, lazy, nested list

```
pascal :: [[Integer]]
pascal = repeat 1 : map (scanl1 (+)) pascal
```

The above definition is a bit terse but what it essentially means is just that each row is an accumulating sum of the previous row, starting from `repeat 1` i.e. an infinite list of ones. This has the advantage that we can calculate each value in the triangle directly without doing any O(n) indexing.

Now you can index the list to find the value you need, e.g.

```
> pascal !! 19 !! 19
35345263800
```

The list will only get partially evaluated for the values you need.

You can also easily output a range of values:

```
> putStrLn $ unlines $ take 5 $ map (unwords . map show . take 5) $ pascal
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 3 4 5
1 3 6 10 15
1 4 10 20 35
1 5 15 35 70
```

Another option is to use your original function but memoize it using one of the various memorization libraries available. For example, using [`data-memocombinators`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators-0.5.1/docs/Data-MemoCombinators.html):

```
import Data.MemoCombinators

pascal :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
pascal = memo2 integral integral pascal'

pascal' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
pascal' 1 _ = 1
pascal' _ 1 = 1
pascal' x y = (pascal (x - 1) y) + (pascal x (y - 1))
```

Comment: great answer. just to add, you can avoid explicit recursion by using `iterate`: `pascal = iterate (scanl1 (+)) (repeat 1)`

Answer (score 3):

The obvious choice for an infinite 2D "array" would be a nested list, i.e. an infinite list of infinite lists. It might thus be

```
pascal' :: [[Integer]]
pascal' = repeat 1 : [ 1 : [ pascalGen x y | y<-[1..] ] | x<-[1..] ]
 where pascalGen x y = pascal' !! (x-1) !! y + pascal' !! x !! (y - 1)
```

This now has the function calls memoised. It's still not optimal because of list *O* (*n*) access, but not that bad either.